# Reinitialisation of Line-array does not remove old lines

Tags: c#, wpf, initialization, line

I have an array of lines say:

```
Line[] myLines = new Line[100];
SolidColorBrush myColor = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(100,100,100));

for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    myLines[i] = new Line() { Stroke = myColor, SnapsToDevicePixels = true };
}
```

Now those lines I use to display a graph according to some datapoints (in this case 100). Now at some point I need to reuse the same line array, namely `myLines`, and NOT declare a new one.
I tried to reinitialise them by:

```
myLines = new Line[200];

for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
{
    myLines[i] = new Line() { Stroke = myColor, SnapsToDevicePixels = true };
}
```

The use of those lines works just fine, but the old ones do not disappear. I thought I have to set the old lines to "null" first:

```
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    myLines[i] = null;
}
```

But that didn't work either. Does anyone have an idea how to solve that problem?

Comment: How do you Display those lines?

Comment: I think I know what you mean. I use `myGrid.Children.Add(myLines[i])` and then just set the coordinates. Do I have to actually remove them as children from grid? I read somewhere that setting them to null will remove them in any case...

Comment: _Do I have to actually remove them as children from grid?_ - Yes. Or create a new grid.

Comment: Okay, but when I remove them as children and reinitialise the array, is that enough to clear the memory allocated, or do I also have to set every individual old line to null first?

Comment: You don't have to set anything to null as long as you clear the lists.

Comment: I will install a check if the old graph array is not null and in that case start a remove of every individual line from grid and then reinitialise, thanks for the fast help. I damn the book where I read my previous information...